# Detecting empty/filled TBlobField fails

Tags: delphi, blob

I have a `fkInternal` calculated field of type `ftBlob` (in a `TClientDataSet`) containing blobs in a DataSnap client application.

The field is initially empty, we only fill it when the blob data are actually required<sup>*</sup>.

This is the code that pulls the data from the server application:

```
var
  lBlobStream: TStream;
  lBlobField : TBlobField;

with DataSet do
begin
  lBlobField := TBlobField(FieldByName(sExpItmFileFile)); // The fkInternalCalc blob
  try
    // Retrieve the blob stream (calculated field) separately when we don't yet have data:
    if lBlobField.isNull then
    begin
      Edit;
      lBlobStream := CreateBlobStream(lBlobField, bmWrite);
      DownLoadAttachmentBlob(FieldByName(sExpItmFileID).Asinteger,lBlobStream);
      Post;
      ...
    end;
```

The blob data are retrieved fine.
My issue is with the `if lBlobField.isNull` test: the next time we come in this code (the dataset remains on the same record, no `ApplyUpdates` is called in the meantime) *this value is still true*.
I have also tried to check the properties `Size`, `DataSize`, `BlobSize`, they are all 0.

**How can I check if my TBlobField contains data?**
(Or am I doing something wrong in this code?)

<sup>* Reason: we don't want to pull all this data in; actually loading a `TClientDataSet` with many blobs gives 'package too large' errors in the RemObjects components that we use</sup>

Edit 1: It probably has something to do with the contents of the field not 'sticking' - in another part of the code directly following the Post `lBlobField.Value` is empty.

Edit 2: This is a dataset with a query across 3 nested tables. `DataSet` is the third level `TClientDataSet` and here the data blobs need to be *written to* the fkInternalCalc field (hence the `bmWrite`, the Edit and the Post), only when they are actually required. They are retrieved through a separate client-server channel by `DownLoadAttachmentBlob`. This gets the record ID as input and puts the blob data in the second param (`lBlobStream`). The (nested) dataset contains all the other fields of the 3rd level table (like ID `sExpItmFileID`), but not its blob data. `DownLoadAttachmentBlob` works OK.
Once a blob is read into the calc field we want to keep it around (not retrieve it twice).

Comment: Sorry if only noise, but you create the blob stream with mode `bmWrite` although you appear to read from it? Also, not knowing what `DownLoadAttachmentBlob()` does exactly, is it right that the blobfield seems to be `sExpItmFileFile` but you pass `sExpItmFileID` to the function?

Comment: @TomBrunberg Sorry for the confusion ;-) See Edit 2.

Comment: Don't litter your post with *Edit 1* and *Edit 2*. We can see which edit changed what by looking at the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38588645/revisions). Just edit the post and add the details as if you'd written them in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution myself, and it completely baffles me:

The `TStream` (var `lBlobStream`) has to be freed before calling the Dataset Post method.

So the relevant code part should be:

```
Edit;
lBlobStream := CreateBlobStream(lBlobField, bmWrite);
DownLoadAttachmentBlob(FieldByName(sExpItmFileID).Asinteger,lBlobStream);
lBlobStream.Free;
Post;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem baffling to me. TFileStream actually writes the file when it is freed as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem in SQL.

Add an extra field in your select statement that details if the blob field is empty or not.

```
select *, ifnull(BlobField, 1, 0) as BlobNull from mytable
```

Now you can just query the `BlobNull` field. Obviously you'll have to adjust the `IfNull` function to match the syntax available in your database. 
An alternative might be to just use the test as a boolean field.

```
select *, (Blobfield is null) as BlobNull from mytable
```

Even better would be not to select all fields, but just pull in the fields needed and exclude filled blobfields using the `where` clause, but I'm not sure your use case allows for this.

Comment: The advantage of solving this in SQL is that you don't have to pull the blobs over the wire if you're not going to use them, which speeds things up a lot.